# Connecting an iPhone to the internet Only with a Stand Apple USB Cable Without Jailbreak

Tags: network, wifi, iphone, internet

I have an iPhone 4S and I don't have a SIM/Data card nor can I connect to the internet using Wi-Fi as the module is broken.

I am using a **Windows 7** Laptop and I'm wondering if it's possible to **connect my iPhone to the internet via a standard Apple USB cable**. I have confirmed my connection to the internet on my laptop. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** My iPhone is not Jailbroken

Comment: This link [here](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2014/08/28/how-to-connect-an-ipad-to-ethernet/) could help you out.

Comment: Thanks @azngeoffdog but I was looking for a solution like internet directly from usb port without using the ethernet port of the computer, just like the opposite version of when we're using phones as hotspots via usb connection

Answer (score 2):

I found some (complex) [instructions](http://forums.imore.com/jailbreaking-unlocking-hacks-themes-mods/232233-use-pc-internet-over-iphone-via-usb-cable.html) here.

But since you have some complex situation with your iPhone, no SIM, no data, and NO WiFi !!, this might work for you.

It describes how to use PC Internet over IPhone via USB Cable.

Important to know is:

First and for most we need a jailbreak iPhone with Cydia installed.

In PC you have to download the latest version of IFunbox v1.9.
Download and install Privoxy v3.0.19.
Download and extract Bitvise Tunnelier

and so on... (to long to copy in here)

I could not verify for you since I do not have your setup.

Comment: thank you for the information but my iphone is not jailbroken and I don't have Cydia, there must be another way for doing this

Comment: It would be helpful and save me time if you add that kind of information in your OP.